# Meaning of the $ f(z+a)$ for complex function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question bothering me very long time.

Say the complex function $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv (x,y)$

Consider the $T : z \to z+a$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ (Here the $a = \alpha + i \beta$)

Then, $f(z+a) = u(x+\alpha, y+\beta) + i v(x+\alpha, y+\beta)$ for $f(z)$

I.e. $f(z+a)$ is the translation by "$- \alpha$" to x axis(real part) and "$-\beta$" to y axis respectively for the both of each $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$.

But the problem is occurred like the below.

I took the example as the $f(z) = z$ with the considering the $g(z)  = z+1 = f(z)+1$. Then we can get the $g$ by  translating the $f$ as the moving the $f$ to the positive real part "$+1$". By the way at the point of the $f(z+1) = g(z) = (x+1) + i (y)$ then, we can get the $g $translating by the negative real part "$-1$".

Hence  even though there are same function, one is maps($f(z)+1$) to $x=1$ but the other($f(z+1)$ ) is maps to $x=-1$ considering the $x=0$

I'm very confused the meaning of the $f(z+a) (= f \circ T)$. What is the exact meaning of that?

Answer (score 1):

It just means the composition of two functions.

Let $z = x+ iy, a = \alpha + i\beta\in \mathbb{C}, x, y, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, and set $T: z \mapsto z + a, f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

First you need to know

$$(f \circ T)(z) = f(T(z))$$

which is the definition of the composition of two functions.

Then since $T(z) = z + a$, we have

$$(f \circ T)(z) = f(T(z)) = f(z + a)$$

which is exactly what you need.

For the example you give, we set $f: z \mapsto z, T: z \mapsto z + 1$, then we have

$$(f \circ T)(z) = f(T(z)) = f (z + 1) = z + 1$$

And there is no $-1$ in the expression.